# Dependency Injection, pass a different logger into the same service

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Im working on a project which talks to multiple serial ports simultaneously. Each of these `Procedures` requires access to the same services but I want each service call to log to a different logger/file. For example, Procedure 1 calls to the API service and should log to file 1 and procedure 2 calls to the API service should log to file 2. As far as I can tell, there are two options but I don't like either of them.

**Option 1:**
For each procedure, I create its own instance of the service(s) with the procedures logger.

```
public IProcedure CreateProcedure(int portNumber)
{
    Serilog.ILogger logger = CreateLogger(portNumber);

    Service1 service1 = ServiceFactory1.Create(logger);
    Service2 service2 = ServiceFactory2.Create(logger);
    Service3 service3 = ServiceFactory3.Create(logger);
    Service4 service4 = ServiceFactory4.Create(logger);
    Service5 service5 = ServiceFactory5.Create(logger);

    List<IStage> stages = new()
    {
        new Stage1(logger.As<Stage1>(), service1),
        new Stage2(logger.As<Stage2>(), service1),
        new Stage3(logger.As<Stage3>(), service1),
        new Stage4(logger.As<Stage4>(), service1),
        new Stage5(logger.As<Stage5>(), service1, service2, service3),
        new Stage6(logger.As<Stage6>(), service1, service4),
        new Stage7(logger.As<Stage7>(), service1, service2),
        new Stage8(logger.As<Stage8>(), service1, service5),
    };
        
    return new Procedure(logger.As<Procedure>(), service1, stages);
}
```

Disadvantage:
Requires a factory for every service, each factory will have to take in the logger that needs to be used.
This could cause performance issues with a large number of procedures by having X amount of each service.

**Option 2:**
I only create 1 instance of the service and have it handle which logger it needs to log to. This could be done with a separate `LoggerCollection` service that gets injected in.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    ILoggerCollection _loggers;

    public Service1(ILoggerCollection loggers)
    {
        _loggers = loggers;
    }

    public void Method1(string value, int comport)
    {
        loggers.Get(comport).LogWarning(comport);

        // Do thing.
    }
}
```

Disadvantages:
Should logging logic code be in an API service?
Each service method requires a parameter to pass in the COM port to work out which logger to log to, this results in a lot of additional parameters.

Does anyone have a better idea of how to do this? Or which option is better?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Option 3: If you extract each procedure into its own class, you would be able to elegantly solve this problem, because you can give each class its own logger, e.g. `class Procedure1` can get an `ILogger<Procedure1>` and `Procedure2` can get its `ILogger<Procedure2>`. Serilog and Microsoft logging allow individual loggers to get different behavior.

Comment: Maybe Im missing something but how would you get service 1 to use ILogger<Procedure1> or ILogger<IProcedure2> under different situations?
I also don't think this would work because each procedure is identical and the number of them required is decided at runtime.

Comment: The suggestion is to use 1 logger per class (not per procedure). Why can't service1 use `ILogger<Service1>`? Are you referring to a procedure as a method? It is just a member of a class, even if it is created at runtime.

Comment: If I use one logger per class, how do I control which file the logger logs into? Or which logger gets injected. From my understanding in typical DI, you have one logger registered at startup and injected into all the services (which is what it sounds like you're describing). But in my case, each service needs to use a different instance of logger depending on where it is being called from.

When you say, 1 logger per class, are you talking about the same logger being converted to ILogger<T> and injected?

Comment: Let's say hypothetically, I need 2 procedures. I register my service1 interface. Then I create my procedures, which creates 2 instances of the service1 interface `_serviceProvoider.GetRequiredService<T>()`, how do I choose which logger is used in procedure 1's service1 and procedure 2's service1